# Simplifying code: classes as simple containers in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function `drag` which can be called as `drag('Object1').to('Object2')`. The code below works as I want, but it seems using a `class` simply as a container may be unnecessary:

```
def drag(source):
    class Container:
        def to(self, target):
            print 'Dragging ' + source + ' to ' + target

    return Container()
```

Can the above code be simplified?

Comment: To my eye, the code looks pretty simple as it is... Out of interest, why use this highly unusual syntax (as opposed to, say, `drag(source, target)`)?

Comment: I find the other syntax much more expressive.

Comment: wouldnt you have a container object that implements a move_to method? `c = Container() ... c.move_to(x, y)`

Comment: @TomIngram: That's also OK, but I prefer my solution.

Comment: Then use your solution. It works, but it's completely unpythonic. aix gave you a pythonic version that would do the same thing, and really should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a class that has a source and when `to` is called takes a target and prints the message. You can call the class `drag`:

```
class drag:
    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = source
    def to(self, target):
        print 'Dragging ' + self.source + ' to ' + target
```

Or you can use a `Container` class as in your code and have `drag` simply be a function that calls the initializer:

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = source
    def to(self, target):
        print 'Dragging ' + self.source + ' to ' + target

def drag(source):
    return Container(source)
```

I will point out that this function doesn't really do any thing useful, and attempting to write a useful class/function like this will make your code less clear without adding anything.